# Core Graphics, odd behaviour with CGContextSetShadowWithColor blur height

Tags: ios, iphone, core-graphics

I've been adding shadows to my shapes using *CGContextSetShadowWithColor*. I'm trying to use the same blur offset height.

However the height of the shadow I'm seeing on different shapes is different. I've no idea why this occurring.

Here's some typical code.

```
CGSize offset = CGSizeMake(0.1, self.l_shadHeight);
CGContextSetShadowWithColor(context, offset, mauveBlurRadius, mauve.CGColor);
```

EDIT - FURTHER CODE

```
+ (NSInteger)setShadowHeight
{
    NSInteger retVal = 10;

    if (IS_IPHONE_6P)
    {
        retVal = 7;
    }
    else if (IS_IPHONE_6)
    {
        retVal = 7;
    }
    else if (IS_IPHONE_5 || TARGET_INTERFACE_BUILDER)
    {
        retVal = 6;

    }
    else if (IS_IPHONE_4_AND_OLDER || IS_IPHONE)
    {
        retVal = 6;
    }
    else if (isiPadPro)
    {
        retVal = 16;
    }
    else if (IS_IPAD)
    {
        retVal = 11;
    }

    return retVal;
}
```

//

```
-(void)setSizingClassValues
{
    self.l_shadHeight = [DrawingConstants setShadowHeight];
}

// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    [self setSizingClassValues];

    //// General Declarations
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    //// Shadow Declarations
    //UIColor* circleShadow = shadowColor2;
    UIColor* circleShadow = [shadowColor2 colorWithAlphaComponent: [DrawingConstants SHADOW_ALPHA]];

    CGSize circleShadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.1, self.l_shadHeight);
    //CGFloat circleShadowBlurRadius = 5;
    CGFloat circleShadowBlurRadius = [DrawingConstants setShadowBlurRadius];
```

//

```
    //// Frames
    CGRect frame = self.bounds;

    CGFloat xPadding = 18;
    CGFloat YPadding = 19;
    CGFloat wPadding = 39;
    CGFloat hPadding = 54;

    if (isiPadPro || IS_IPAD)
    {
        if (self.size == sizeSmallerPerformance)
        {
            //so we don't have to rework autolayout on other screens!
            CGFloat fac = 2;
            xPadding = xPadding / fac;
            YPadding = YPadding / fac;
            wPadding = wPadding / fac;
            hPadding = hPadding / fac;
        }
    }

    //// Subframes
    CGRect group = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + xPadding,
                              CGRectGetMinY(frame) + YPadding,
                              CGRectGetWidth(frame) - wPadding,
                              CGRectGetHeight(frame) - hPadding);
```

//

```
    //// Abstracted Attributes
    CGFloat circleSurroundStrokeWidth = self.l_borderWidth;
    CGFloat tongueLeftStrokeWidth = self.l_strokeWidth;;
    CGFloat tongueStrokeWidth = self.l_strokeWidth;

    //// Group
    {
        //// CircleSurround Drawing
        UIBezierPath* circleSurroundPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect: CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(group) + floor(CGRectGetWidth(group) * 0.00164) + 0.5, CGRectGetMinY(group) + floor(CGRectGetHeight(group) * 0.00161) + 0.5, floor(CGRectGetWidth(group) * 0.99836) - floor(CGRectGetWidth(group) * 0.00164), floor(CGRectGetHeight(group) * 0.99839) - floor(CGRectGetHeight(group) * 0.00161))];

        CGContextSaveGState(context);
        CGContextSetShadowWithColor(context, circleShadowOffset, circleShadowBlurRadius, circleShadow.CGColor);
        [circleFillColour setFill];
        [circleSurroundPath fill];
        CGContextRestoreGState(context);

        [whiteColour setStroke];
        circleSurroundPath.lineWidth = circleSurroundStrokeWidth;
        [circleSurroundPath stroke];

    }

    //// Cleanup
    CGGradientRelease(innerFaceGradient);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);   
}
@end
```

Comment: Do you have a self-contained, reproducible case? Two lines of code is not enough to determine anything. Are you sure `self.l_shadHeight` is always the same value? And are you sure the results you see are caused by this specific code, and nothing else?

Comment: Yeah the self.l_shadHeight is always the same. There's no difference in that line. I'm just wondering if the frame size set to self.bounds and auto layout adjusting the view size could be reducing the sizes ? Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @KurtRevis I guess I could add some code showing that if it would help?

Comment: That depends on what these two lines of code are drawing into. If this is just in a view's `-drawRect:` then I can't think of anything terribly common that would cause the drawing to be rescaled, although there are ways (e.g. the view's `contentMode` being set oddly). If it's drawing into an image that you use later, then it would depend on how you use the image. I could guess all day, but running a reproducible case would be much faster.

Comment: Also, is it *only* the shadow whose height is not what you expect, or is other drawing in the same place also affected in the same way? And in what way is your result different -- larger, smaller, nonexistent? By how much?

Comment: @KurtRevis ok I've added some implementation code, I've stripped it down a bit.

Comment: @KurtRevis I guess you have nothing to add and what I'm doing should be ok?

Comment: There is nothing obvious wrong that I see. Best I can suggest is to construct an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that someone could build and run to see the problem happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found this issue, I had my shadow on the wrong thing. Instead I added it to my outermost group.

Thanks @kurtrevis